# Multiple hasMany() associations with different foreign keys

Tags: orm, cakephp-3.0

I am implementing a simple system that allows recording transactions between users. For that I have two tables `transactions` and `users`.

Every transaction is between two users and records the flow from one user to the other in the fields `from_user_id` and `to_user_id` which are foreign keys to `users.id`.

Now I would like to get all transactions for an user (in reverse chronologically order). I'd love to have something like this:

```
class UsersTable extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config) {
        ...
        $this->hasMany('Transactions', [
            'foreignKey' => [
                'OR' => [
                    'Users.id = Transactions.from_user_id',
                    'Users.id = Transactions.to_user_id'
                ]
            ],
            'finder' => [
                ...
            ]
        ]);
        ...
    }

}
```

Of course this does not work out (`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Transactions.Array' in 'where clause'`) and setting `foreignKey` to `false` and using a custom `queryBuilder` is not allowed for `hasMany` associations.

What does work is using two different associations for both foreign keys (one for *negative* and one for *positive* transactions) and then merging the two, but I would rather not go this way. This is the current approach:

```
$this->hasMany('NegativeTransactions', [
    'className' => 'Transactions',
    'foreignKey' => 'from_user_id'
]);
$this->hasMany('PositiveTransactions', [
    'className' => 'Transactions',
    'foreignKey' => 'to_user_id'
]);
```

Has anybody any ideas?

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#associations-linking-tables-together see 3rd example

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm doing now. Edited the question

Comment: Why dont you make an union? http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#unions